# Laravel not found http exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I have a simple controller where I want to get content from a page using guzzle, however I am having trouble viewing any of the results because I keep getting error "NotFoundHttpException"

My route:

```
Route::get('hello', 'GuzzleController@test');
```

Controller:

```
function test(){
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', ['auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']]);
    echo $res->getStatusCode(); // 200
    echo $res->getBody(); // { "type": "User", ....
    return view('hello');
}
```

view:

```
{!! $res !!}
```

Comment: Can you access this `controller` by typing in: `'http://{url-name}/hello'` on your browser?

Comment: http://localhost/laravel/public/hello this is what I type and I get nofoundhttp exception, but if I type http://localhost/laravel/public i do get laravel main page

Comment: try localhost/laravel/public/index.php/hello

Comment: same error, i never had any problems but now not even a simple return view works

Comment: @Przemek when you finally get your answer to the question, try to mark the answer and close the question. At least a simple thank you to people who try to help you would do, instead of opening non stop questions without resolving them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you're trying to access the routes without setting up the web root for url rewriting. Run `php artisan serve` from you laravel application folder and then access the site like so

```
http://localhost:8000
http://localhost:8000/hello
```

Or set up the local web server to point to the laravel application public folder as the root.

Comment: well I am using xampp and it is definetely working as localhost/laravel/public gives me laravel home page. however my link "hello so localhost/laravel/public/hello gives me an error

Comment: @Przemek that's exactly the problem. You can't run the application with your htdocs root following the folder using xampp localhost. If you do then the only route that would work is `/`. How hard is it for you to even test out the answer before commenting?

Comment: it isn' hard I have tested your solution and I get exactly the same problem http://localhost:8000 works and http://localhost:8000/hello doesn't

Comment: | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api // sorry for the layout but it looks like the route is not there?

Comment: You don't even have the route registered. Where have you added the route? Try running `php artisan route:clear`